# MySQL joining table into query which has no refference with others

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to make a query from muliple prestashop tables to be able to import it to another database. The problem is that the third table has no refference to the other two and couldn't figure out how I can join them together.

To simplify things lets say the 3 table looking like this:

```
Table1  Table2           Table3
ID      ID | Table1 ID   ID
------  --------------   ------
1       11 | 1           12
2       22 | 1           13
3       44 | 2           
        55 | 2
        66 | 3
        77 | 3
```

And I would like this result:

```
firstID | secondID | thirdID
1       | 11       | 12
1       | 22       | 12
1       | 11       | 13
1       | 22       | 13
2       | 44       | 12
2       | 55       | 12
2       | 44       | 13
2       | 55       | 13
3       | 66       | 12
3       | 77       | 12
3       | 66       | 13
3       | 77       | 13
```

Or in words, I would like to assign everery Table3 ID to every Table2 ID and also display Table2's refference to Table1 aka Table1 ID

When I query Table1 and Table2 I usually do it like this:

```
SELECT p.`id` AS `firstID`, pa.`id` AS `secondID`
FROM `Table1` p
LEFT JOIN `Table2` pa ON (p.`id` = pa.`id`)
GROUP BY pa.`id`
ORDER BY p.`id`
```

But I wasn't able join the third table in so it would produce the desired outcome.

How can I achieve the above mentioned result?

Comment: Try my solution and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Renamed table ids to match OPs table structures.

```
SELECT t1.`ID` AS `firstID`, t2.`ID` AS `secondID`, t3.`ID` AS `thirdID`
FROM `Table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `Table2` t2 ON (t1.`ID` = t2.`Table1 ID`)
LEFT JOIN `Table3` t3 ON 1
ORDER BY t1.`ID`, t3.`ID`
```

This gives same result as you expect.

```
SELECT t1.`ID` AS `firstID`, t2.`ID` AS `secondID`, t3.`ID` AS `thirdID`
 FROM `Table3` t3, `Table1` t1
 LEFT JOIN `Table2` t2 ON (t1.`ID` = t2.`Table1 ID`)
 ORDER BY t1.`ID`, t3.`ID`
```

Comment: nope this won't work. look at the posted table structure and data again carefully

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for  `cross join` with `inner join`. Try :

```
Select 
a.ID, b.ID, c.ID
from 
Table1 a Inner Join 
Table2 b on a.ID = b.Table1_ID
Cross Join 
Table3 c
```

This will fetch table1 and table2 based on ID and table3 will be cross joined with result.

More about cross join can be found [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cross-join/)

Comment: I tried your solution and looks like its working too.